# Perfectly parallel problems in Rust

Tags: multithreading, rust, parallel-processing

I'm struggling to see how I could best implement a common concurrency pattern I use in c++.

Pseudocode:

```
void kernel(inputs, outputs, start, stride) {
  for (size_t i = start; i < length(inputs); i+=stride) {
    outputs[i] = process(inputs[i]);
  }
}
void run(inputs, number_of_threads) {
  threads = []
  vector outputs(length(inputs))
  for (int i = 0; i < number_of_threads; i++ {
    threads.push(thread(kernel, inputs, &outputs, i, number_of_threads));
  }
  for t in threads {
    t.join()
  }
return outputs
}
```

That is, doing some function over lots of inputs by striding over the input space. It's perfectly parallel, never has race conditions etc. But with rust's ownership model, each kernel would need a mutable reference to outputs, so I don't understand how it could work.

What's the safe way to do this simple problem in Rust?

Comment: You may want to take a look at [rayon](https://docs.rs/rayon/latest/rayon/)'s parallel iterators.

Comment: I've had a look but I'd like to know how this can be implemented myself, as its a pattern that comes up a lot.

Comment: You really just shouldn't. This pattern is not conducive to Rust's ownership/borrowing model. Just use rayon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`splice::split_at_mut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.split_at_mut) to separate the array into separate sub-slices, each with their own mutable reference. You can pass the first slice to a [`scope`'d thread](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/thread/fn.scope.html) then continue splitting the second slice.